# Dynamo DB table design

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have table where i want to store a child's activity. Currently i have table as below, and it supports my queries

Queries

1. Get Activities for child
2. Get activities for room

**Additional requirements that i want to support**

3. In application layer if an activity is for multiple, children. I am duplicating activity for each child, i.e if activity was 3 kids, then three records are created one for each child. This results in duplicate results for get activities for room query, but i merge them in application layer. Not ideal, and concern one
4. Now i want to support adding comments. for comments i was thinking, adding flag in activity to tell if there is comment(comments=true/false). Then separate record for each comment
   Activity in Child_Id  have "comment_[child_id+timestamp of activity]" createdDateTime[ timestamp of comment].
   Now on UI of there is any activity that has comments flag set to true, i will user query 1, with child as "comment_[child_id+timestamp of activity]"

Can you suggest better design but keeping the table same.

**Activity**

```
Child Id [partition ]
createdDateTime [Primary Sort key]
Room id [GSI partition ]
createdDateTime [GSI Sort key]
School id
Image_name
Additional attributes
```

Comment: Is it your goal to use a single DynamoDB table?

Comment: yes i want to keep, activity related data in same table